# Limited control over EIP

Tags: python, gdb, overflow, eip

I am trying out some simple buffer overflows and i have control over my EIP but it seems to be limited to a strict set of characters.

For example i have an python script that does the following

```
buff = "A" * 128
buff += struct.pack("<L", 0x42424242)
sys.stdout.write(buff)
```

This correctly overwrites my EIP to : 0x42424242
I can change the value of 0x42424242 to 0x42434445 for example and it will still work.

But as soon as i enter reall an address like : 0x804843b my EIP will change to an invalid address like 0x000000

Basicly every address i enter here instead of the 0x42424242 that does not resolve to an alphabetical character i get an invalid EIP address:

Works:

```
buff += struct.pack("<L", 0x42424242)
buff += struct.pack("<L", 0x45454545) 
buff += struct.pack("<L", 0x41424344)
```

also all of these above will result into alphabetical characters when printed like 
AAAA
EEEE
ABCD

does not work:

```
buff += struct.pack("<L", 0x804843b)
```

when printed this also shows we characters like: 
;�

Comment: are you trying to add `x42424242` or `0x42424242` ? Your code throw an error.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: `struct.pack("<L", x42424242)` throws an error. The second element must be an integer or a hex. Otherwise, contatenating a string (utf8) with a byte will throw another error.

Comment: Sorry it was an typo, i edited it. But the 0x41414141 address works. And when i print it it will show me AAAA but when i do an address like 0x8048300 it does not work and it prints characters like this: : ;�

Comment: `struct.pack("<L", 0x804843b).decode("utf16")` will print `萻ࠄ'`

Comment: Yes it does print that. But that is not what i expect. pack("<L> , 0x41414141) now prints 䅁䅁 while i expect it to print AAAA

Comment: Did you tried `struct.pack("<L", 0x41414141).decode("utf8")` ? it prints `AAAA`

Comment: Printing 0x41414141 is not the problem. That is what works as expected.

Comment: So please edit your question and add the exact problem and what you've done to get the error.

Answer (score 0):

struct.pack("<L", <some_numeric_value>) returns the numeric value in the little endian format. Little endian format of 0x41414141 is \x41\x41\x41\x41. But when it prints this out in a console or terminal, each hex value is converted to it's corresponding ASCII character. That is, \x41 is converted to 'A' and so on. So

> print struct.pack("<L",0x41414141)

prints 'AAAA'.

The little Endian format of 0x804843b is \x3b\x84\x04\x08. 0x3b is the ASCII value of ';'. 0x84, 0x04 and 0x08 are non printable characters.
Thus

> print struct.pack("<L", 0x804843b)

prints out  ;� where � is standing for the non-printable characters.